# SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.1.0, version solving failed

Tags: java, flutter, programación-móvil

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto antiguo que usa Flutter y al compilar me muestra el siguiente error:

> Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Users\miuser\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit
> value 1

Si ejecuto desde la terminal flutter pub get, obtengo la siguiente advertencia:

> Resolving dependencies in .....  The current Dart SDK version is
> 3.1.0.
>
> Because miApp requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.1.0, version solving
> failed.

Esta es la configuración en mi pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.1.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  camera: ^0.5.8+5
  barcode_scan: ^3.0.1
  http:
  audioplayers: ^0.16.1
  shared_preferences:
  device_info_plus: ^0.5.0
  package_info_plus: ^0.5.0
  honeywell_scanner: ^4.0.0+14
```

¿Cómo podría resolver este problema para poder compilar la aplicación? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que conseguir una versión más vieja de Dart SDK. La que tienes no está soportada.

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta, qué versión necesitaría? Cual sería mejor?

Comment: Leé de vuelta el mensaje: _Because miApp requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.1.0, version solving failed._ De hecho eso es lo que explícitamente está en tu pubspec.yaml: dice `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.1.0"`: como mínimo _2.12.0_ y menor a _3.1.0_. Hacele caso a lo que dice tu archivo de configuración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya te han contestado en los comentarios, pero te amplío la respuesta.

El mensaje de error te indica que la versión de Flutter que tienes, 3.10, no concuerda con las restricciones de tu archivo pubsepc. El cual indica que las versiones aceptables van desde la 2.12.0 inclusive hasta la 3.1.0 (no incluida).

Aquí tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambia la restricciones de versiones en tu archivo pubspec para poder usar la versión de Flutter que tiene tu máquina ahora mismo.

Para ello, lo que yo haría sería crear un proyecto nuevo y ver que versiones pone en el archivo pubspec. Las puedes copiar y pegar en tu proyecto nuevo, sustituyendo: `">=2.12.0 <3.1.0"`.

Esto seguramente te obligue a actualizar las dependencias del proyecto y si alguno no tiene una versión que se pueda usar en esta nueva versión, te va a tocar sustituirla o quitarla.

2. Borra la instalación de Flutter de tu sistema e instala una versión que esté dentro de las que tu proyecto puede usar `">=2.12.0 <3.1.0"`.

Si no quieres perder tu versión de Flutter, puedes tener múltiples instancias de Flutter en una misma máquina usando [Flutter version managment](https://fvm.app/es/). El cual te ayuda a gestionar proyectos con diferentes versiones de Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

Instala fvm aqui:
[instalar fvm](https://fvm.app/es/)

- Esto consiste en cambiar tu path que originalmente estaba en /User/flutter/bin -> al nuevo -> /User/fvm/default/bin
- Luego como en la documentacion indica instala en **paralelo** la version **3.0.0** luego configuralo con tuproyecto con **fvm use 'version`**.
- Finalmente obtienes lo packages como normalmentese hacia.